# How to search for a place within specified area or city in Google Maps Using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF wordpress plugin)

Tags: php, wordpress, google-maps, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF Wordpress Plugin) to create a google map  field.

I have an area (multiple cities in Morocco) on the map described by geographical coordinates (longitude and latitudes). Is there a way to pass this set of coordinates to google API and limit search results within this area? Or simply search in specific cities ?

I found some examples but i didn't know where to put the code. i found some actions like "google_map_init" and "google_map_args"  but i'm not sure.

this code helps me to strict the search by country (MA : MOROCCO ).but i need to strict the search by regions or cities.

```
acf.add_action('google_map_init', function( map, marker, $field ){
         map.autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({country:'MA'});
});
```

Thank you

Comment: plz share your examples so that we could help you to find where to put the code.

Comment: this code helps me to strict the search by country (MA : MOROCCO ).but i need to strict the search by regions or cities.

acf.add_action('google_map_init', function( map, marker, $field ){
         map.autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({country:'MA'});
});

Comment: Place autocomplete component restrictions support only country. If you need filter by specified area you should use bounds and strictBounds properties set as per documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-widget#AutocompleteOptions

Answer (score 1):

You could set your Component Restriction by  postalCode to restrict by city

```
acf.add_action('google_map_init', function( map, marker, $field ){
         map.autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({country:'MA', postalCode: "2000"});
});
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but it didn't work. the search result didn't show anymore. i used a valid postalCode.

Comment: sorry, I have no place to test the function but I guess it's a problem with brackets and or comas. The postalcode is an official restriction element https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. i changed the brackets and comas but still not working